# Request through curl works but request through Axios doesn't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, axios

I created a VPC with public subnets and private subnets to create 2 aws EC2 servers.
My API server lives in a private subnet and my React server lives in a public subnet. The React server can connect to API server. When I use cURL to send request from React server to the API server, the API server responds with no errors. Ping requests from the React server to the API server also work without problems.

However, when I type into my web browser `<React server's public IP>:3000` and send the same request with a browser, Network tab of Chrome Developer complains `Failed to load resource data: No data found for resource with given identifier`. I'm using Axios to make requests to the API server.

I tried copying headers of browser requests to cURL requests to reproduce the issue in cURL but cURL still works.
My API server does not log anything when a request is made through browsers so I guess my Axios request does not reach the API server.